# Get the list of custom taxonomy terms by count which have custom post_type posts

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

In my WP v5.9.3, I have custom post type "song" and a shared custom taxonomy "genre".

On the Songs archive page, I want to list all the terms of "genre" taxonomy with count, which have posts in "song" post type.

With `get_terms` I was able to get all the terms from "genre", but cannot filter terms which has "song" posts.

Though I am not expert at SQL Query, I have tried below but not able to get the list:

```
    $SQLquery = "SELECT wp_terms.* COUNT(*)from wp_terms
                 SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
                 INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
                 INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                 INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
                 WHERE 1=1 
                 AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('song')
                 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
                 AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'genre'
                 GROUP BY wp_terms.term_id
                 ORDER BY wp_terms.term_id DESC";

    $SQLqueryResult = $wpdb->get_results($SQLquery, ARRAY_A);

    $SQL_term_ids = wp_list_pluck($SQLqueryResult, 'term_id');
```

How can I make the above SQL query work to get the terms list or is there any simple / built-in WordPress function?
Thank you.

**Update 1**

Issue was with multiple `SELECT` in `SQLquery`, when removed `SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts` the code worked as required.

Comment: I'm none of them, but maybe I'm allowed to explain anyway? ;) Without knowing your table structure and data, it is difficult to help. There is an issue concerning the begin of your query. You can't use two selects like this. When you want to select multiple columns, you need to use comma, meaning "select table1.column1, table2.column1...from yourselection."

Comment: @JonasMetzler, you were right. It was the duplicate SELECT. I have removed that and I am getting the terms from specific custom post type.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, please respond as answer, so I can accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, done, thanks for leaving feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue concerning the begin of your query. You can't use two selects like this. When you want to select multiple columns, you need to use comma, meaning "select table1.column1, table2.column1...from yourselection."